# Can UUIDs be typed?

Tags: slick

Let's say we have an ordinary parent-child relationship between two tables, `employers` and `employees`.

The field `employerId` in `employees` is really only comparable to `id` in `employers` (and to `employerId` in other tables).  In the interests of type-safety, I would like to represent `employers` as

```
class Employees(tag: Tag) extends Table[Employees](tag, "employees")  {
  def id = column[UUID[Employees]]("id") 
  def employerId = column[UUID[Employers]]("employerId")
 ...
}
```

Comparing a `UUID[Employers]` column to anything other than another `UUID[Employers]` column, or using any comparison besides equality would be nonsensical (in most schemata, including mine), and I'd like to capture that fact at compile-time.

Obviously, the real UUID does not take a type-parameter but this need is common.  Can it be done?

Comment: What about using a container/wrapper class, _e.g._ a case class, which contains the UUID internally but which, for purposes of consuming code, is itself the ID?  You'd get the type checking you like, but would have to do just a little extra work, in terms of accessors, to use the contained/wrapped UUID.

Comment: @Castaglia -- I was looking for a specific _existing_ type or type-library.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36338795/238884) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer seems to be [Unicorn](https://github.com/VirtusLab/unicorn) from Virtus Labs.

> This library adds tools to use type-safe IDs for your classes so you can no longer join on bad id field or mess up order of fields in mappings. It also provides a way to create data access layer with methods (like querying all, querying by id, saving or deleting) for all classes with such IDs in just 4 lines of code.